# Regex XSD Pattern matching to not allow duplicates

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I defined the following regex to allow any possible combination of

- 1 to 7 digits
- having values 1-7
- having no digit twice

Regex: ^(?!.1-7.*\1)[1-7]+$

- 1 --> valid
- 12 --> valid
- 153 --> valid
- 6234 --> valid
- 123344 --> not valid
- 1236547 --> valid
- 12345678 --> not valid

...it works find in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/c02YZA/1) but XML validation always reports an error.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are many different dialects of regular expressions. The one in XSD is quite restrictive (a deliberate decision for ease of implementation). Your regex is not valid in the XSD dialect, and I don't think it's possible to achieve this validation using XSD regular expressions.